# Tail probability of a Poisson random variable (curious equality of two series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

For a Poisson random variable $X$ with rate $p$, and a positive integer $k$, the tail probability is given by $$P(X\ge k)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty e^{-p} \frac{p^n}{n!}$$

The same value is produced by $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty (-1)^{n-k} \frac{p^n}{n!} {n-1 \choose k-1}$$

Do you have any suggestions for showing the equality of these two series?

Apart from calculations that I'm interested in seeing, I wonder if there is also a neat interpretation of these sums that explains their equality that I'm not aware of.

Comment: An approach that seems to work is to expand out $e^{-p}$ by its infinite series expansion and exchange the resulting sums.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $\displaystyle e^{-p}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-p)^n}{n!}$,

it's just a matter of checking that $\displaystyle \bigg(\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{p^n}{n!}\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-p)^m}{m!}\bigg)=\sum_{a=k}^\infty (-1)^{a-k} \frac{p^a}{a!} {a-1 \choose k-1}$

which, by taking these as Taylor series in $p$ and comparing coefficients, is just a matter of checking that for each $a\geq k$ we have

$\displaystyle\sum_{b=k}^a \dfrac{(-1)^{a-b}}{a!}{a\choose b}=\frac{(-1)^{a-k}}{a!} {a-1 \choose k-1}$

which you can do by fixing $a$ and inducting downwards for $k$:

it's obvious for $k=a$,

and then subtract the LHS for $k=j$ from the LHS for $k=j+1$, in order to check that it is the same result subtracting the RHS for $k=j$ from the RHS for $k=j+1$.